# List out the Facebook Request received in Unity 3D

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Given that I can send out App Requests to other Facebook friends by the following codes:

```
// in a button event
FB.AppRequest("Let's Play!", null, null, null, 50, "", "Play Now!", FriendRequestCallback);
```

Here is the callback function:

```
private void FriendRequestCallback(FBResult result) {
    if(result != null) {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error)) {
            // Failed Case
            lastResponse = "Friend Request Callback: Error Response:\n" + result.Error;
        } else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text)) {
            // Success Case
            lastResponse = "Friend Request Callback: Success Response:\n" + result.Text;
        }
        Debug.Log(lastResponse);
    } else {
        Debug.Log("Friend Request Callback: Response is empty");
    }
}
```

How can I list out the App Requests received by the logged in users? And how can I accept the request in Unity 3D?

*Note: I'm using Facebook SDK for Unity 6.0*

---

To list out App Requests, I know I can use FB API calls: `/me/apprequests` with **GET**.

To accept a specific App Request, I can use:

```
http://apps.facebook.com/[app_name]/?request_ids=[REQUEST_IDs]
```

Reference:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/apprequests